# Есть ли http:// или нет?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать на `JS (Java Script)` такую проверку: Есть поле:

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'URL'>
```

И мне нужно сделать проверку, если в поле нет `http://`, то в начале строки дописать `http://`. Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то в лоб: проверить подстроку с 0 до 7 символа, если она не равна http://, то => его нет и добовляем

**UPD: добавил пример**

```
var url="test.com";
if (url.substring(0,7) != "http://")
url = "http://" + url;
alert(url);
```

Comment: Можно и так.

Comment: Imho, один из тех случаев, когда самое простое решение будет самым приемлимым, не вижу смысла городить что-то хитрее.

Comment: Дело в том что я в js новенький и до этого с ним не сталкивался... Поэтому даже самого простого не знаю.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 4):

```
var normalizeUrl = function (url) {
    if( !/^https?:\/\//i.test(url) ) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
    return url;
}
```

Пример использования — http://jsfiddle.net/ufLs7/